Exporting animations made with curve geometry to FBX format
As shown below, I created a surface using Extrude from Geometry in the Nurbs Curve function, and used an add-on called AnimAll to create an animation that moves the belt by capturing keyframes at the points of the curve.
Then, when I exported this as FBX and checked it in another program (VRED), it was imported as a belt without animation applied.
If I mesh it with the 'Convert Mesh' function, I can export it as FBX, but the keyframes I specified are deleted.
Is there a way to import a mesh as FBX and apply animation to it?
Unfortunately, the .abc format does not work properly in VRED...
I'll also upload the file I'm working on.



https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-te
